# How to extract RadGrid EditableItem into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, telerik-grid, radgrid

Is it possible to extract the edited row from a RadGrid into a DataTable object?

The examples I've seen online show how to extract the data into a HashTable, but once you do that, you lose the data type (string, datetime, ect).  We're building a generic grid that can display different tables, so we don't want to have to hard code the columns/data types.
If the data is in a DataTable, then it can be passed directly to a SQL stored procedure that accepts a Table Value Parameter.